# Linux bond mode 802.3ad not activated

Tags: debian, cisco, switch, bonding, lacp

on a server running **Debian Stretch** I configured a **bond0** with the **802.3ad mode** as following:

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        slaves eth0 eth2
        bond_miimon 100
        bond_mode 802.3ad
```

The **bond0** interface is up and and running but it's working with the **load balancing (round robin)** mode:

```
root@servir01:~# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 2
Permanent HW addr: e4:1f:13:65:f0:c4
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 2
Permanent HW addr: e4:1f:13:36:a3:ac
Slave queue ID: 0
```

On the switch the LAG is correctly created with the LACP enabled and it has both ports up and running:

[[image: LAG status[1]]

[image: Status of the Unit3 / port1]

[image: Status of the Unit4 / port1]

The same machine has another bond interface **(bond1 on eth1 and eth3 interfaces)** configured in the very same way, connected on the same switches, and the LACP is working good:

```
Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: e4:1f:13:65:f0:c6
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 2
    Actor Key: 9
    Partner Key: 1010
```

**Why the bond0 interface doesn't want to enable the LACP?
Where I am wrong?**

Comment: What have you got in modprobe for bonding? On EL, you don't need to have anything. Not sure how the Debian initscripts work but I expect you could also get away with nothing as well.

Comment: Note that the correct syntax is not `bond_mode 802.3ad` but `bond-mode 802.3ad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem adding the following to the bond configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
bond_xmit_hash_policy layer2+3
```

After adding this configuration and restarting networking everything is working well.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but since it comes up pretty early in searches, and I had a similar setup, with the same problem. Here's how I got it working, (using ifenslave on Debian stretch)...

/etc/network/interfaces...

```
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # bond0 is the bonded NIC and can be used like any other normal NIC.
    # bond0 is configured using static addressing.
    auto bond0
    iface bond0 inet static
    address <your static address>
    gateway <your gateway>
    # bond0 uses standard IEEE 802.3ad LACP bonding protocol
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 0 (This is on a small NAS, so no rush)
    bond-slaves none

    # eth0 is manually configured, and enslaved to the "bond0" pseudo NIC
    allow_hotplug eth0
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

    # eth1 ditto, thus creating a 2-link bond.
    allow_hotplug eth1
    auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
```

What was the cause?

Well, the NICs would come up, the bonding driver would grab them, then the NICs would go down to reconfigure to be slaves, and the bonding driver would panic 'cos it had no slaves, and ran around like a headless chicken (round robin).

Now, the bonding driver comes up, sees that it has no slaves, so it sits back and waits... The NICs see that they have a master, so they go and report in, get their addresses from bond0, and off to work they all go.

Answer (score 2):

tested on debian 10 (after reading this thread and the debian bonding documentation)

config is below (no other files edited - modules or something like that)

```
auto enp4s0f2
allow-hotplug enp4s0f2
iface enp4s0f2 inet manual
        bond-master bond1
        bond-mode 4

auto enp4s0f3
allow-hotplug enp4s0f3
iface enp4s0f3 inet manual
        bond-master bond1
        bond-mode 4

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet static
        address 1.2.3.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bond-mode 4
        bond-slaves none
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond-updelay 800
        bond-downdelay 400
        bond_xmit_hash_policy layer2+3    # optional, sets the bonding algorithm
```

what's new:

- interfaces are brought up BEFORE the bond
- the bond mode is specified also @ interface level
- the bond has no slaves defined

Comment: was ifenslave installed?

Answer (score 2):

Have spent few days after Debian 10 buster upgrade (full-upgrade) to Debian 11 Bullseye, so want to share the bonding issue solution.

After Debian Linux upgrade, existing trunk configuration is not working anymore. There are breaking changes, referred as bugs:

- https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.html
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=990428
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=968368

And previously on Debian 10 working bond0 configuration was like this:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/bond0

auto enp9s0f0
iface enp9s0f0 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        bond-mode 4

auto enp9s0f1
iface enp9s0f1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        bond-mode 4

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 192.168.23.1
        network 192.168.23.0
        netmask 255.255.255.128

        bond-slaves none
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1         # 'fast' detection, every 1s, instead of 'slow', every 30s
#        bond-updelay 100        # optional, mostly for debugging
#        bond-downdelay 100      # optional, mostly for debugging
        bond-xmit-hash-policy layer2+3    # optional, sets the bonding algorithm
```

which resulted in no **bond0** configured or even errors like these:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave exited with return code 1
networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

or

```
journalctl -n -u networking
```

showing error line

```
No iface stanza found for master
```

where 'stanza' is so called module configuration, term used by developers.

The root cause of that is the ​`ifenslave` package was refactored a lot, main idea ​was to remove the "stanza" from child items, which are physical interfaces (nic), and keep it all in one place, e.g. **bond** interface it self.

Also even in `ifenslave` version 1.22 bug left, referring to nonexistent command `ifstate` in Debian 11. Easy and quick fix is:

```
sed -i 's/ifstate -l/ip link show dev/g' /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
```

Even after fixing this, bonding does not work, this means there are bugs of issues why bonding is not working on Bullseye.

Going through the code I found that the key change was not only to remove `bond-mode` from child and put it back to **bond** interface configuration, like it was in early package days, but also revert back to the early format of `bond-slaves`.

Thus working Debian 11 Bullseye bonding configuration file looks like this:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/bond0

auto enp9s0f0
iface enp9s0f0 inet manual
        bond-master bond0

auto enp9s0f1
iface enp9s0f1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 192.168.23.1
        network 192.168.23.0
        netmask 255.255.255.128

        bond-mode 4
        bond-slaves enp9s0f0 enp9s0f1
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-lacp-rate 1         # 'fast' detection, every 1s, instead of 'slow', every 30s
#        bond-updelay 100        # optional, mostly for debugging
#        bond-downdelay 100      # optional, mostly for debugging
        bond-xmit-hash-policy layer2+3    # optional, sets the bonding algorithm
```

Update 2022:

Recently on one of metal servers I got issue, that after kernel upgrade and removal of old kernel, system become networkless.
Long story short - there can be case, that bonding kernel module is not loaded, not present, or any loading failure because of version mix up, or initrd mess-up. Check that with:

```
lsmod | grep bond
bonding               167936  0
```

If it's not there, this is a culprit of the problem. Try to load module manually `modprobe bonding` and check if it loads. Investigate does loaded kernel version corresponds to what is supposed to be `uname -r` and check if modules directory is present for that version.

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Comment: The actual reason is that `ifenslave` (together with `ifconfig`, `route`, `brctl`, `tunctl` and many others) is *long time obsolete*, and `ip` from `iproute2` should be used instead. That's why Debian 10 and 11, RHEL starting from 8 and so on don't even have `net-tools` (an obsolete redundant crap) installed by default.

Comment: No sure which backend neplan uses, still some aspects like bonding module is still very actual to resolve problems. In Ubuntu neplan managed networks also had issues, thus sharing.